# axios preflight http status code 500

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I can't seem to make the yelp API work for me. I get past the first ajax but the I get error on the second.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

I am running this on localhost:3000 and I'm using Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * extension on Chrome.

This is my code on client side:

```
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token',
    data: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
                + '&client_id='+api[0]
                + '&client_secret='+api[1]
  }).then(res => {
      USER_TOKEN = res.data.access_token;
            const AuthStr = 'Bearer '.concat(USER_TOKEN); 
            axios.get(api[2], { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } })
            .then(res => {
              // If request is good...
              console.log(response.data);
              })
             .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error ' + error);
            });
    })   
   .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error ' + error);   
   });
```

Comment: how does `api.yelp.com` respond to `OPTIONS` requests?

Comment: `and I'm using Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * extension on Chrome` - this "cheat" obviously doesn't help with preflighted CORS requests - so, you'll need to use api.yelp.com as it was meant to be used, server to server

Comment: So I can't run it on localhost?

Comment: oh, wait - is that your server side code you're showing, or is that browser code - nevermind, must be browser seeing as there's a preflight AND it's using XMLHttpRequest - so, your question about "run it on localhost" is invalid since you're running this code in the browser not on the localhost server

Comment: Yeah this is browser code. Can I not do this in browser code?

Comment: clearly `api.yelp.com` chokes on an OPTIONS request (verify by viewing the request in your browser developer tools network tab)

Comment: Idk what OPTIONS request is. I only know get and post. :/ What should I do to make this work?

Comment: don't make the request in a browser - the API you deal with does not allow CORS, your attempt to bypass this with an addon has failed, because you can't fool preflighted CORS requests with an addon :p - you'll need to interact with that API in server side code

Comment: Figured I would have to do that. :/ Thank you so much. Last question though, so can I update the view in real time without refreshing the page if I put it on server side?

Comment: well, the browser would request from **your** server, which would make the request of the remote server, and send the response it receives from the remote server back to the browser - or, in other words, your server should proxy the request

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been plenty helpful!